# How can I flatten the response using RxJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Right now for the operation mentioned in title I have the following code

```
from(["url_1", "url_2"])
  .pipe(
    concatMap(url=> this.vocabularyService.getSimilarProducts(url)
      .pipe(concatMap(x => x.items))
    ),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

What it does that for each **URL** in the array of **URLs** it makes an API call that returns something like this

```
class Response {
   items: Object[] // this is a specific type, but let's omit this for simplification
}
```

After receiving the response I again need to do a `concatMap()` to retrieve each of the `items` array `item` and eventualy I do the `toArray()` to somewhat flatten each `item` into single array and log it into console.

Does RxJs have any specific operator to do this kind of thing or is it possible to avoid my stacking of `concatMap()` operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) to flatten the array like so.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { from, of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, reduce } from "rxjs/operators";


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  subscripber = {
    next: (i) => console.log(i),
    complete: () => console.log('end'),
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    from(['url_1', 'url_2'])
      .pipe(
        concatMap((url) =>
          of({
            items: [1, 2, 3],
          })
        ),
        reduce((acc, one) => {
          acc.push(...one.items);
          // remove all the duplicates!
          return [...new Set(acc)];
        }, [])
        // smaller version
        // reduce((acc, one) => [...acc, ...one.items], [])
      )
      .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
    // Open the console in the bottom right to see results.
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-ye1jdc)

Comment: Considering that ```item``` has some property ```id```. Is it possible to accumulate only distinct by ```id``` elements? If so please add this your answer.